# Ember App Kit and ember-oauth2

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

I am new to Ember and am trying to use https://github.com/amkirwan/ember-oauth2 library with my Ember App Kit based Ember App.

I have searched a lot but I cannot find the following answer:

**ember-oauth2 creates a App.oauth global that is needed elsewhere**

App.oauth = Ember.OAuth2.create({providerId: 'google'});
App.oauth.authorize();

then I want to access it in my controllers. However, the "App" object is not available in controllers. How do I access global objects defined at the App level in my controllers?

It also uses window.App.oauth variable in callback HTML so post compilation I need the oauth global to be available.